# Extremely mysterious behavior of the disappearing .bbl file when compiling using TexStudio, no idea what could be causing this!

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texstudio

My .bbl file completely gets wiped out every time I compile. What could be causing this extremely weird behavior?

[image]

[image]

**Steps that seems to reproduce this error:**

1. Compile a .tex file stored in Path 1, call it A.tex
2. Compile a .tex file stored in Path 2, call it B.tex
3. Compile A.tex again.
4. A.bbl has been wiped out. Empty. Nil. Zilch.

Here is the error message immediately after I perform 3.
[image]

Note that A.tex and B.tex are literally random tex file that I downloaded from Arxiv! I could reproduce with arbitrary files A, B that I find and download from Arix, and even default templates that I find online.

What on earth could be causing this? It is extremely expensive and time consuming to replace a .bbl file.

Some other error message that seems to be helpful:
[image]

Comment: As it says in the last image (and please never show images of code), it cannot find your bib file, use `\bibliography{VIbib} ` not `\bibliography{VIbib.bib}`. In the latter case bibtex will be liking for a file with .bib.bib which does not exist. Don't just ignore errors like that

Comment: You wrote, "Note that A.tex and B.tex are literally random tex file[s] that I downloaded from Arxiv". Downloading (and compiling) "literally random tex files" is such a safe and wholesome thing to do, isn't it? What could possibly go wrong? You asked, "What on earth could be causing this?" Rather than rely on readers' psychic divination skills (I wouldn't count on them), you might edit your query and post the bibliography-related code from the "literally random tex files" in question. That way, people will actually have a chance to examine the code and determine where it's gone off the rails.

Comment: especially random files copied off the internet are you _sure_ you want to use `--shell-escape` that is giving your "random file" full control to access or delete any file on your machine that you have access to. It is disabled by default with good reason.

Comment: but you show in your question why there is no bbl. a bbl file is not a source file it is generated by bibtex and in your case bibtex gives an error that it can not find the source (due to an error in the tex it is looking for `VIbib.bib.bib` with a double extension so it could not find any source data so gave an error and generated an empty bbl file